# Python Docker Container gets ProxyError, despite I can connect to Server manually

Tags: python, docker, proxy, python-requests

Really weird problem here. I have a Python Application running inside a Docker Container which makes requests in  different threads to a http restapi. When I run the Container, I get the error:
`ERROR - host not reachable abc on thread abc. Stopping thread because of HTTPConnectionPool(host='corporate.proxy.com', port=111111): Max retries exceeded with url: http://abc:8080/xyz (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))`

When I log in onto the docker host and make the request with curl, then it works.
When I execute the request inside the docker container (docker exec ....), then it works.
When I start the python interpreter inside the container and make the request with the requests module (like application does it), then it works.

The Container is attached to the host network of the docker host machine

Did anyone had also an issue like this?

Comment: does this happens only on docker startup? try adding some delay to check if service startup is causing the issue?

Comment: @Tarique Thx for the Input, I will try it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Tarique and others I've found the solution:

I've added a startup delay of 30 seconds to the container to connect to the docker host network correctly. Then startet the requests.session. Additionally I removed the http_proxy and https_proxy env var from the container.